# AttributeError in MessageFwdHeader telethon library

Tags: python, telethon

I'm getting AttributeError in my code. How can I fix it please

```
from telethon import events

@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def _(event):
    x = await event.get_reply_message()
    if x is None:
        return
    send = event.raw_text
    who = event.sender_id
    if x.fwd_from:
        user = x.fwd_from.sender_id.user_id
    else:
        return
```

Error:

```
Line 11: AttributeError: 'MessageFwdHeader' object has no attribute 'sender_id'
```

Comment: Okay, so when you *read* the error message `Line 11: AttributeError: 'MessageFwdHeader' object has no attribute 'sender_id'`, did you look at line 11 of your code? See how it says `who = event.sender_id`? Does it make sense to you that `event.sender_id` should do something? What should it do? Why? What are you expecting `event` to be? Is it actually that? What does the documentation say?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: line 11 is actually `user = x.fwd_from.sender_id.user_id` btw

Answer (score 0):

the AttributeError usually use a not existence attribute  ,check the object Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.forward) and [this](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.sendergetter.SenderGetter.sender_id) in the docs it is possible to get the original sender ID like: `message.forward.sender_id`. By the way the result will be `None` if the sender's profile was hidden or that was a channel repost.